# How To Send A Signal To A Socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, signals, shared-memory

In my scenario, a client and a server establish a connection and exchange their Process ID's and a shared-memory-location ID. After this process has completed the server ends the connection and waits for a signal. When the Client writes some information into the shared-memory, it sends a signal to the server which then goes to the memory location and prints the date.

How should i go about this please help!!!

Comment: Exactly as you have outlined it.  Start coding and when you reach an impasse ask a question.  Note that you aren't sending a signal to a socket.  The socket will provide the PID that you can use in `kill` to send a signal to the server.

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com to get an overall picture of all this, and also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a socket for all your communication.

Sockets have a useful feature called half-open connection. That is, one side can finish sending data and send end-of-file to the other side using `shutdown(socket, SHUT_WR)`, but still wait for incoming data. The other side can keep reading data till receiving the end-of-file, send data and eventually also  do `shutdown(socket, SHUT_WR)` or `close(socket)`.